A ValueTask can be awaited only once - what does it mean?
I want to use ValueTask. I found somewhere that "a ValueTask can be awaited only once ". I cannot await for the method GetMoney multiple times or what? If yes, how should I change my code?
public class CreditCardService
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> _cache = new Dictionary<int, int>()
    {
        { 1, 500 },
        { 2, 600 }
    };

    public async ValueTask<int> GetMoney(int userId)
    {
        if (_cache.ContainsKey(userId))
        {
            return _cache[userId];
        }

        //some asynchronous operation:
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var money = rnd.Next(100);

        _cache[userId] = money;
        return await Task.FromResult(money);
    }
}

var creditCardService = new CreditCardService();
Console.WriteLine(await creditCardService.GetMoney(1));
Console.WriteLine(await creditCardService.GetMoney(3));
Console.WriteLine(await creditCardService.GetMoney(3));


In addition to the answer below, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/understanding-the-whys-whats-and-whens-of-valuetask/ for more details.

See also https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html

@Sweeper I wouldn't trust that person further than I could throw them...

@MarcGravell regarding your previous comment below my answer: I want to understand the issue better: what exactly is the difference between an object and an instance in this context ? According to this post they refer to the same thing. AFAIK in C++ for example they are also the same.

@wohlstad typically, "object" is used in .NET to refer to a heap object, i.e. an allocation; this could be an instance of a class, or a "boxed" struct. A value-type (struct) can be treated as an object, but this is not an identity preserving operation: when a value-type is treated as an object, an additional allocation is required. In short, a value-type that is treated as that value-type is semantically different to a typical object. To add confusion, the various specifications use slightly different meanings for some of these terms.

@MarcGravell thanks for the clarification. I was not aware that in C# (unlike e.g. C++) a value type instance is not cosidered an object (strictly speaking).

@wohlstad struct vs class in C# is completely different to struct vs class in C++

@MarcGravell that is actually something I am aware of (in C++ they are essentialy the same up to default access private/public, and in C# they are fundamently different - value type v.s. reference type). My gap was just with the terminology and you certainly clarified that point.

return await Task.FromResult(money); seems pointless, there is nothing actually async here.

You are awaiting each task exactly once:
var creditCardService = new CreditCardService();
Console.WriteLine(await creditCardService.GetMoney(1)); // a new ValueTask
Console.WriteLine(await creditCardService.GetMoney(3)); // a new ValueTask
Console.WriteLine(await creditCardService.GetMoney(3)); // a new ValueTask

The following would be awaiting a single task multiple times:
var creditCardService = new CreditCardService();
var money1Task = creditCardService.GetMoney(1)
Console.WriteLine(await money1Task);
Console.WriteLine(await money1Task);


Each time you call GetMoney you get a new ValueTask instance.
Then you await each of these ValueTask instances exactly once.
Therefore your code is not violating this rule.
In order to violate the rule, you would need to await the same ValueTask instance more than once.
Some more information about ValueTasks can be found in this .NET blog: Understanding the Whys, Whats, and Whens of ValueTask.
